# Check If Input Is a Number, Turn Input Into String With JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

This code is returning `268`, but it's returning `268` as a *number* when I'd like for it to return `134134` as a *string*:

```
function numbersToStrings(input1, input2) {

    let newString = " ";

    if (input1 === Number) {
        input1 = input1.toString();
    }
    if (input2 === Number) {
        input2 = input2.toString();
    }

    return input1 + input2;
}

console.log(numbersToStrings(134, 134));
```

I've checked if the input is a number with `if (input1 === Number)` - is that not a valid way to check if something is a number in JavaScript?

I'm working on a problem that does not allow the use of `.concat()` or `.join()`, so please tell me why my number check isn't working, or why `.toString()` isn't working.

Thanks.

Comment: `typeof input1 === "number"`

Comment: *"is that not a valid way to check if something is a number in JavaScript?"* No. You are checking whether the value is equal to the `Number` **function**. And there is only one value for which this is true, `Number` itself.

Comment: `Number` is the global object `window.Number`, which definitely isn't what you want

Comment: Do you want  `134 + 134` to be 268 as a string or `134134`?

Comment: You need to do the math with numbers before converting to string if you want to add them

Comment: @MarkMeyer true, it should return `134134` - not `268`. I'll edit that.

Comment: @MarkMeyer that's true, I'm trying to get it to work here:

https://www.codewars.com/kata/es6-string-addition/train/javascript

And was checking if the inputs are numbers first.

Comment: If you're comfortable with ES6, I'd suggest just using `return \`${input1}${input2}\``

Comment: @p.s.w.g Yeah that returns exactly what I'm looking for - thanks.